# How can we enable -shell-escape to tex4ht's htlatex or related program?

Tags: tex4ht, shell-escape, htlatex

Can we enable `-shell-escape` through any option without editing the default `htlatex` program? **OR** Can we achieve this using `mk4ht ht`?

Comment: try `mk4ht htlatex <file> "--shell-escape"`

Comment: @Herbert: Sorry that argument is for the cfg! But, thanks it give me a hint to trace and finally I got the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got the answer:

The `-shell-escape` option should be passed as the **fifth** argument to `htlatex`.

```
htlatex <filename> <cfg> <ht-font-dir-for-tex4ht> <option-to-t4ht-program> <tex-command-line-option>
```

So an example would be:

```
htlatex test.tex config.cfg "xhtml,charset=utf-8" -utf8 -shell-escape
htlatex test.tex config.cfg "" "" -shell-escape
```

Source: `htlatex.bat`